# What's causing these 301 redirects?

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, jwplayer

As part of my internship, I'm working on a salespage http://www.BritishBoxBreakout.com/BBBSystem/index.html or http://www.BritishBoxBreakout.com/BBBSystem/index1.html the page itself seems to load fine, but the area where jwplayer shows up is black. I originally thought the player was at fault, until I got firebug.

When I run firebug against `/BBBSystem/index.html` or `/BBBSystem/index1.html`, I notice a bunch of 301 redirect requests pointing to `/zerotofifty.html`.

There is no .htaccess file in that folder, except for the standard .htaccess generated by wordpress in the root of the domain.

I did set up a Google Website Optimizer project for a page named 'zerotofifty.html' I'm not sure if that's what would cause the redirect. I closed that GWO project just in case, and am still having the redirect problems.

I went to http://web-sniffer.net and redirectcheck.com and checked those pages both of which returned code 200. So I think the web pages are loading properly.

My guess would be some sort of element in the page is causing the redirect, but I can't find it.

Any suggestions as to what would be causing this?

[edit] I figured out the problem. There was a resource where the 404 error page was redirecting somewhere else on the site. I have since fixed the problem and everything loads within half a second.

Comment: Just put all the JWplayer files (jwplayer.js, skins folder etc) into the wp-content folder. And of course update the your html file to use `wpcontent/jwplayer.js` etc.

Comment: I tested the page, it loads just fine. If you solved your problem please Answer it and close it (2 days after the answer).